# Free CI/build server with different Linux versions

Tags: linux, build, continuous-integration

I would like to build my dynamic library on different Linux platforms (e.g. RHEL 5/6/7, ...). I use https://drone.io at the moment, but it provides only Ubuntu.

Could you recommend something please?

It'll be perfect, if it can provide some "cool" features, e.g.:

- free for open source projects
- github integration (hooks)
- CI/tests
- artifact download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)  or [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/recent) should suit your purposes